# Chromium on startup behavior is different that launching it manually

Tags: chromium, autostart

I have a Jetson Nano that runs LXDE. After booting it should automatically start Chromium in kiosk mode and launch a web page. The web page is very simple, just adding and removing some rectangles or images based on web socket messages.

Since sometimes the DOM gets updated, sometimes not, I thought my web page has some bug. But this behavior is only on the Jetson Nano. Furthermore, when I launch the Chromium manually with the exact same parameters, I have no problem at all, everything runs as expected.

I also observed that the Chromium (the autostarted one) instantly updates the DOM correctly when I press Alt+Tab (since it is the only application, no application is really switched). So apparently nothing has happened since the last web socket message, I just press Alt+Tab, and the web page instantly is displaying the correct things. Additionally it is very difficult to bring up the developer console, pressing ctrl+shift+i for several minutes, when you are lucky it fires up the developer console. Once it is there, the web page is again working normally.

I have no idea what I can do about it. I just want to launch the Chrome so it behavior is like when I start it normally.

Currently, the autostart is done inside  `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart` with the line `@/home/agx/dev/autostart/chromium.sh`, this file is:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 60
chromium-browser --new-window --password-store=basic -kiosk --js-flags='--jitless' http://192.168.1.50/index.html
```

I tried to delay the start hoping it would help but it changed nothing. Same for jitless. I can execute exact this command manually in the console, chromium fires up and behaves normally.

How can I trace this one down?